# How can i ignore a DbUpdateConcurrencyException with my Entity Framework code?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

**Is there any way I can tell EF to not worry about the number of rows a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` do or don't do?**

I'm trying to delete a row from the database, but because the row doesn't exist, EF throws an exception: `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` .. saying *0 rows were affected*. This is right -> no rows were deleted. But that's totally fine .. cause there's no data.

I don't really want to do a round-trip to the DB to see if that row exists .. and if so .. then try and delete it.

If i try and swallow the exception in a `try / catch` block, then the rest of the items to be deleted do NOT get sent to the db, when I try to `SaveChanges()` ... which is bad.

eg.

```
Delete(new Foo(1));
Delete(new Foo(2));
Delete(new Foo(3));
SaveChanges(); // <-- Throws the exception.

// DB Trace : DELETE FROM Foo WHERE Id = 1;
```

and thats it.. there's no trace showing record 2 or 3 trying to get deleted .. because the exception stops everything :(

Any ideas?

#### UPDATE

How does `Delete` work? Here's the code... (simplified and strongly typed)

```
public void Delete(Foo foo)
{
    if (foo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
    }

    Foo attachedEntity = Context.Set<Foo>().Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id > 0);

    if (attachedEntity != null)
    {
        // Entity already in object graph - remove entity.
        Context.Set<Foo>().Remove(attachedEntity);
    }
    else
    {
        // Entity not in object graph, attach and set EntityState to Deleted.
        Context.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does Delete function work?

Comment: @LukLed - edited OP with extra code.

Comment: I understand that these deletes are a part of bigger operation and can't be made independently?

Comment: Even if they were made independently, the same problem exists -> trying to delete a DETACHED object which doesn't doesn't exist in the DB. I don't care if the row exists or not - > just try and remove it. If it's not there, no probs. if so, then delete. Done. /me slaps EF.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this? It's a major pain when performing multiple operations in a single SaveChanges call.

Answer (score 2):

I think the behavior of EF is correct - simply you must execute commands only for objects which are present in DB. It is not for scenarios like: "I will try it and we will see...". If you can't be sure that object exists in DB and you don't want to do round trip (which I think is the best idea because deleting detached object can have several other pitfalls especially if object participates in independent associations) you should use `DbContext.Database.SqlCommand` and run store procedure.

The correct way to handle `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` is described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/03/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-9-optimistic-concurrency-patterns.aspx) => After each exception you should resolve confilicts (in your case it means remove problematic entity from DbContext) and execute `SaveChanges` again.

Comment: Ah :) Earlier today I was exerimenting with using a try/catch around the `Context.SaveChanges()` to handle any `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` exceptions .. but all I was doing was a Refresh() .. then SaveChanges() again .. which of course didn't work (threw the same error). Can u update you answer to include HOW u remove the offending entity from the Context, please?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: I would try to use ChangeTracker and set entity state to Detached.

Comment: can u please elaborate on your previous comment, please?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Try to use `exception.GetEntry(dbContext).State = EntityState.Detached;` Where exception is catched `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`. If this doesn't work you will simply have to check that entity exists before you mark it as deleted.

Comment: I disagree with the answer, the behavior of EF is not correct. Think of it this way - User A does SELECT, exists. User B does exist, exists. User A deletes, succeeds. User B deletes, fails with exception. In both cases the result should be the same - we're deleting the record. Sure, there's a conflict, but the result is the same - a deleted row. There's nothing to resolve. "Checking to see if it exists first" doesn't work - it's a race condition. Can't lock on reads in all cases, in our case we're using MySQL Cluster - no read locks.

Answer (score -1):

You can in fact ignore these kinds of issues by setting:

`db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

Where `db` is the DbContext instance.

Obviously you should know what you're doing when you do this, but then again, most approaches to updating a database that are not EF don't have any change tracking/validation and just issue update/insert/delete to the database naively without checking anything first, so you're basically just telling EF to behave more like that.

Comment: Are you sure? ValidateOnSaveEnabled controls data annotation validation, not concurrency. My understanding is that (as of EF 4.3) there's no way to suppress the DbUpdateConcurrencyValidation for deletes.

Comment: I tested the above claim before posting; I created 2 DbContexts, used one to fetch an object, another to fetch, change, and save an object, and then finally attempted to change and save on the first one. I got an Exception; changed the above setting to false, ran again, no Exception.

In addition, have you checked the documentation? It refers to validating the entity, not the schema: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.validateonsaveenabled(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Doesn't work, a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` still gets thrown. I tested with 2 instances of a DbContexts. Edited an entity in the first and set `ValidateOnSaveEnabled` to `false`, then deleted the entity in the second context and saved, then saved on the first but it throwns the exception.